# How to determine the object type pointed to by a reference type?

Tags: soql, developer-console

I have an Account object with a custom field, `manager__c`. The custom field type is reference.

Using the developer console, how do I find the object type pointed to by an instance of `manager__c`.

I have `manager__c` `id` (e.g., 007o0000002aEyaFAE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write some Apex to do this through the dev console (using the "Anonymous Apex" feature. The Salesforce CLI can also run "anonymous apex" via `sfdx force:apex:execute -f <relative path to a file with apex> -u <username or alias>`).

Given an Id, you can get the name of the SObject that Id is for.

```java
// You don't need to store this in a separate Id variable
// You could just operate directly on myAccount.Manager__c, I'm just doing this
//   for clarity
Id unknownId = myAccount.Manager__c;

// From the Id, we can get the SObject type
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = unknownId.getSObjectType();

// From the SObject type, you can get the "describe" information, which
//   gives you access to the name (as well as a slew of other information)
String objName = sobjType.getDescribe().getName();

System.debug(objName);
```

or in one line

```java
System.debug(myAccount.Manager__c.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName());
```

Alternatively, for simple cases using standard objects, you can look at a list of the Id prefixes (like [this one from FishOfPrey](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html), who has contributed a great deal here) to do this without code. The first 3 characters of an Id is the "prefix", and tells you what object you're working with.

If you're doing any work in code, though, then getting the SObject's "Describe" info is a better approach (compared to trying to use the first 3 characters of the Id to do a comparison).